# Clojure repeated `defmacro` wrapping a form that creates a Java class

Tags: clojure, macros

I'm wrapping `defrecord` with a `defmacro`, because I want a specific type of concrete map to register itself with a central place (for serde).

The macro is:

```
(defmacro def-thing! [name [& fields] & opts+specs]
  `(let [klass# (defrecord ~name ~fields ~@opts+specs)
         map-constructor-fn# (resolve (symbol (str 'map-> ~name)))]
     ; use the map-constructor-fn#
     ))
```

The problem is that the `let` form gets macroexpanded differently based on whether the macro has already been called before (like when I reload the namespace source file in nrepl).

The first time, `name` is a Symbol.

The second time, `name` is a Java class.

I can, of course, test to see if `name~` is a Java class, and then call `.getSimpleName()` and do the appropriate thing.

But the core contributors to Clojure must have run into this? How is this handled? And why don't I see an explicit solution in the Clojure core source for `defrecord` or `emit-defrecord`? What am I missing?

Comment: Not entirely relevant, but just to clarify, shouldn't the parameter list be `[name fields & opts+specs]`? Or is your calling syntax different from the `defrecord`?

Comment: The `[& fields]` form I took from the `defrecord` signature. The destructuring essentially is shorthand for forcing `fields` to be a `seq` without doing a `:pre` form. I think.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm an idiot. I found this in "Joy of Clojure":

```
(defmacro def-thing! [name [& fields] & opts+specs]
  `(let [klass# (defrecord ~name ~fields ~@opts+specs)
         map-constructor-fn# (resolve (symbol (str 'map-> '~name)))]
     ; use the map-constructor-fn#
     ))
```

Notice the `(quote (unquote <symbol>))` - i.e. `'~<symbol>` - form. That idiom forces capture of the raw, unqualified symbol passed in.

The curious thing is that I'm ***not*** passing that to the `defrecord` call. Internally, `defrecord` does the same capture of raw symbol, except through a `var` call, presumably because `defrecord`, when called the first time, would assign the symbol to a fully qualified class var. In fact, `'~name` specifically ***does not work*** with the `defrecord` call, and I get a `clojure.lang.Cons cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Named` exception.

This seems like inconsistency to me, but what do I know?